# In IPython Notebook, how to programatically get the screen resolution, browser window width and current notebook cell width?

Tags: python, html, css, jupyter-notebook, screen-resolution

I want to set the widgets' width depending on the width of the notebook window. The resolution of the user's computer, their current window size and how they setup the css for their notebook  can all affect this.

Is there a way to get the screen resolution, browser window width and / or current notebook cell width in Python code?

Comment: You can get it with Javascript easily enough...

Comment: any easy way to get in Python? passing the value from JS to Python sounds a bit of a detour... Thanks!

Comment: Why detour? It's deliberately made very [easy](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/06/01/ipython-notebook-javascript-python-communication/).

Comment: So no Python API to do this ? Would appreciate an example in JS. Thanks!

Comment: If it's so "easy", could you _helpfully_ provide a simple example, please? @PanYan Have you figured out how to get the cell width programmatically? I've only seen examples on how to set it, not get it.